# How to resolve Application timeout issue due to SQL Query in 'Killed/ROLLBACK' Scenario

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I've an application which has a database in SQL server 2012 and the application use entity framework to communicate with database. In the application, there is a functionality to update a record in a table based on a WHERE condition and the Primary Key field is the one used in the WHERE condition. So the update happens only to a single record (there is no loop or anything just an update to a single record). This is the background.

Here is the issue now I'm facing - I'm getting a timeout error message from the application when I invoke the functionality to update a record in the table (as mentioned above). I checked the query execution in the SQL server using 'Activity Monitor' and under the 'Processes' tab I could see that the Command of this query comes to 'KILLED/ROLLBACK' after some 'Wait Types' (like LOGBUFFER, pageiolatch_XX, etc...)

I tried to execute the update query directly in SQL server and that also not responding. So it's clear the issues is with the SQL server and it takes too much time to execute the update query. But the execution plan looks good and the PK field is used as the where condition. Is it something related with disk latency?

Note: This issues is not consistent, sometimes it works.

Here is the file stat. How can I interpret or reach a conclusion from these data...

My DB
DbId   FileId TimeStamp   NumberReads          BytesRead            IoStallReadMS        NumberWrites         BytesWritten         IoStallWriteMS       IoStallMS            BytesOnDisk          FileHandle

---

2      1      -1152466625 21199845             1351872315392        2528572322           21869447             1424883785728        10201419039          12729991361          28266332160          0x0000000000000C64
2      2      -1152466625 1063                 45187072             87119                1013000              61628433920          178901888            178989007            6945505280           0x0000000000000CC4

TempDB
DbId   FileId TimeStamp   NumberReads          BytesRead            IoStallReadMS        NumberWrites         BytesWritten         IoStallWriteMS       IoStallMS            BytesOnDisk          FileHandle

---

18     1      -1152466625 390905               27728437248          52640514             196501               6927843328           817347538            869988052            58378551296          0x0000000000001F3C
18     2      -1152466625 24840                1596173312           645024               56563                3335298048           2590871              3235895              938344448            0x00000000000012BC

[image]

Comment: Yes, the disk is slow to respond. Either it is completely overwhelmed or it is broken. Is this a cloud server? Looks like it from the tab name.

Comment: when you execute the query from the application, run sp_who2 from SSMS to see if you're getting blocked. Also, if you can share the actual query and schema details that will be helpful. IO_COMPLETION is an indicator of potential disk bottlenecks but there are a number of possible causes. You can run SELECT * FROM ::fn_virtualfilestats(db_ID('myDB'),x) and replace myDB with your database name and x with the various file ids you have. Do it for your database and tempdb. That gives you additional clues on where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Yes, it's a cloud server. Also, I checked the latency of the DB and it shows the Read Latency =134 and Write Latency = 3913. It's very bad I think. Please share your thoughts.